# converting varchar (TIMESTAMP) to DATETIME

Tags: datetime, timestamp, varchar

I have a column name TIMESTAMP (varchar) which comes from a .dat file. I want to convert it to DATETIME. I know that varchar cannot be converted to a meaningful datetime. But, is there any workaround. There is no way that i can skip this column. Please HELP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is the info stored in the varchar in?  Being a varchar just means it is string like, doesn't say anything about what the information represents.  Depending on the format, you'll probably have to parse out the date info manually.

Comment: please add more details: which language do you use? .dat file is binary or text? do you use a database?